# Count occurrences of given character per cell

Tags: google-sheets

**Question**

For example if I wanted to count the number of `N`s in a column of strings how can I do this in Google Spreadsheets at a per cell basis (i.e. a formula that points at one cell at a time that I can drag down)?

[image: String/Count table]

**Background**

I'm having to decide a threshold `-min-overlap <integer>` for a program called [TOMTOM](http://meme-suite.org/tools/tomtom)** which compares similarity between PWMs*** of small DNA motifs****, `N` is a regular expression for any linear combination of the letters A, C, G and T. It would be nice if I could get an idea of the distribution of non-N lengths of my DNA motifs to help inform me of a proper `-min-overlap <integer>` value for TOMTOM.

And here are some real examples:

[image]

** TOMTOM is a tool for comparing a DNA motif to a database of known motifs. See [here](http://meme.nbcr.net/meme/tomtom-intro.html) for more info.

*** PWM stands for Position Weight Matrix:

- [According to Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_weight_matrix): A position weight matrix (PWM), also known as a position-specific weight matrix (PSWM) or position-specific scoring matrix (PSSM), is a commonly used representation of motifs (patterns) in biological sequences.
- [According to this paper](http://msb.embopress.org/content/13/2/910), it could be defined as:

> Position weight matrix (PWM) or PWM‐like models are widely used to
>   represent DNA‐binding preferences of proteins (Stormo, 2000). In these
>   models, a matrix is used to represent the TF‐binding site (TFBS), with
>   each element representing the contribution to the overall binding
>   affinity from a nucleotide at the corresponding position. An inherent
>   assumption of traditional PWM models is position independence; that
>   is, the contribution of different nucleotide positions within a TFBS
>   to the overall binding affinity is assumed to be additive. Although
>   this approximation is broadly valid, nevertheless, it does not hold
>   for several proteins (Man & Stormo, 2001; Bulyk et al, 2002). To
>   improve quantitative modeling, PWM models have been extended to
>   include additional parameters, such as k‐mer features, to account for
>   position dependencies within TFBSs (Zhao et al, 2012; Mathelier &
>   Wasserman, 2013; Mordelet et al, 2013; Weirauch et al, 2013; Riley et
>   al, 2015). Interdependencies between nucleotide positions have a
>   structural origin. For example, stacking interactions between adjacent
>   base pairs form the local three‐dimensional DNA structure. TFs have
>   preferences for sequence‐dependent DNA conformation, which we call DNA
>   shape readout (Rohs et al, 2009, 2010).

**OR, more contemporarily:**

> Based on this rationale, an alternative approach to augment
>   traditional PWM models is the inclusion of DNA structural features.
>   Models of TF–DNA binding specificity incorporating these DNA shape
>   features achieved comparable performance levels to models
>   incorporating higher‐order k‐mer features, while requiring a much
>   smaller number of parameters (Zhou et al, 2015). We previously
>   revealed the importance of DNA shape readout for members of the basic
>   helix‐loop‐helix (bHLH) and homeodomain TF families (Dror et al, 2014;
>   Yang et al, 2014; Zhou et al, 2015). We were also able, for Hox TFs,
>   to identify which regions in the TFBSs used DNA shape readout,
>   demonstrating the power of the approach to reveal mechanistic insights
>   into TF–DNA recognition (Abe et al, 2015). This capability was
>   extensively shown for only two protein families, due to the lack of
>   large‐scale high‐quality TF–DNA binding data. With the recent
>   abundance of high‐throughput measurements of protein–DNA binding, it
>   is now possible to dissect the role of DNA shape readout for many TF
>   families.

**** DNA motif: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_motif): In genetics, a sequence motif is a nucleotide or amino-acid sequence pattern that is widespread and has, or is conjectured to have, a biological significance. For proteins, a sequence motif is distinguished from a structural motif, a motif formed by the three-dimensional arrangement of amino acids, which may not be adjacent.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

An alternative for one cell at a time (formula to be copied down):

```
=len(A2)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"N",""))
```

Comment: This also works in Arrayformula: =ArrayFormula(len(A2:A7)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A7,"N","")))

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought it would be clear that 'the whole range' was referring to the whole of the range used in the formula ?

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A6, "[^N]", "")))` is better, cause it's shorter, mentions the range only once, and gives you better flexibility with regular expressions

Answer (score 26):

I don't know if this is gonna help but let's say you have those strings in range A2:A6 and you enter

```
=ArrayFormula(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A6, "[^N]", "")))
```

in B2, that should output the N count for the whole range.

Comment: Ohh.. It uses regular expression to replace non-N characters with empty!

Comment: This answer is better than `len-len` cause it's shorter, mentions the range only once, and gives you better flexibility with regular expressions. Vote up!

Comment: interesting enough to +1

Answer (score -1):

```
=len(A2)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"N",""))
```

this works, but if you want to find all numbers matching a specific pattern, say, 3. Then:

```
=len(A2)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"3",""))
```

Is what you need.