# Count occurances of characters in a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I've got a table with some data in a column. Let's say the column looks like this (using commas to represent the end of one cell and the start of the next):

```
ABC, ACD, AABBCF, EFGGHH, AAABCDE
```

I want to write a formula that will tell me how many times the letter A shows up in that column, across all the cells. In this case, the answer is 7 times. So, like, I want to concatenate all the cells, and then count how times A shows up in that whole long string. How would I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrences of given character per cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154682/count-occurrences-of-given-character-per-cell)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

**One way:**

**1.** Create a new [`Named function`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQ0dwMPe6Is) using this formula

```
=FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(range), "(.)", "$1_"), "_"))
```

[image: Named Function in Google sheets]

**2.** Use this formula in a cell

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(TO_SINGLE(A92:A98),,0),LAMBDA(uni, 
          {uni,COUNTIF(TO_SINGLE(A92:A98),"="&uni)}))
```

This second formula will give you 2 columns. The first one with all the unique characters and the second one with their occurrence times.
*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

**Another way:**

Instead of using a `Named function` and a second formula, one can use this single formula

```
=LET(range, FLATTEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(A92:A98), "(.)", "$1_"), "_")),
  BYROW(SORT(UNIQUE(range,,0),1,1),LAMBDA(uni, {uni,COUNTIF(range,"="&uni)})))
```

[image]

---

Functions used:

- [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123)
- [`BYROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)
- [`LAMBDA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)
- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)
- [`LET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535)

Comment: Out of curiosity. Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? Was it something else you were looking for? Any kind of reaction would be highly appreciated.